# Как из одного файла удалить строки из другого файла?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

Как из *файла1*, содержащего строки вида `почта:имя:фамилия:возраст`, удалить те строки, которые содержатся в *файле2*, где указана просто `почта`

Нашёл решение, но оно мне не нравится, слишком долгое и записывает файл миллион раз - боюсь ссд угробит ))

```
for a in `cat файл2`; do sed -i -e "/$a/d" файл1; done
```

Comment: Запиши в /tmp, а потом закинь на ssd.

Comment: может есть решение поизящнее ?

Comment: Ну как ещё вариант - не использовать -i внутри цикла. А выплёвывать в файл уже после всего for'a. Вроде должно проканать. Проверить не на чем.

Comment: попробывал - почему то тоже не то - стал созадвать файл и его размер рос как на дрожях

Comment: @donRumata, тогда в результат попадут множество раз дублированные строки из исходного файла.

Comment: _"записывает файл миллион раз - боюсь ссд угробит"_ - навряд ли. Если файл целиком помещается в ОЗУ, то в реальности он будет прочитан и записан на SSD лишь единожды, благодаря дисковым кэшам

Answer (score 4):

можно за один проход по `файл1` сделать:

```
$ sed -i -f <(...) файл1
```

где `...` — команда, формирующая список регулярных выражений. регулярные выражения можно использовать ваши же — `/искомая строка/d`, а можно чуть уточнить — `/^искомая строка:/d` — добавив привязку к началу строки и к символу `:`.

т.е., вместо `...` предлагаю использовать что-то вроде `sed 's,^,/^,;s,$,:/d,' файл2`

итог:

```
$ sed -i -f <(sed 's,^,/^,;s,$,:/d,' файл2) файл1
```

если в файлах такие строки:

```
$ cat файл1
почта1:имя1:фамилия1:возраст1
почта2:имя2:фамилия2:возраст2
почта3:имя3:фамилия3:возраст3
почта4:имя4:фамилия4:возраст4
почта5:имя5:фамилия5:возраст5
$ cat файл2
почта2
почта5
```

то результат будет такой:

```
$ sed -i -f <(sed 's,^,/^,;s,$,:/d,' файл2) файл1
$ cat файл1
почта1:имя1:фамилия1:возраст1
почта3:имя3:фамилия3:возраст3
почта4:имя4:фамилия4:возраст4
```

---

на всякий случай уточню: при использовании опции `-i` программы *sed* временный файл на самом деле всё-таки создаётся, в него и поступают результаты обработки исходного файла. а по окончании обработки исходный файл удаляется, а временный переименовывается в «исходное» имя.

Comment: Тестирую, блин как же долго,  файл1 = 1гиг файл2= 300 метров, понимаю что быстро не варик, смущает другое, почему он создаёт файл который растёт по 1 килобайту в секунду, что это за файл такой ? результатирующий ? или буфер ?

Comment: @3amunyk, я же специально описал в конце ответа смысл опции `-i`

Comment: @3amunyk, подозреваю, что во втором файле есть дубликаты. оптимальнее их удалить до формирования регулярных выражений: `$ sed -i -f <(sort -u файл2 | sed 's,^,/^,;s,$,:/d,') файл1`

Comment: дубликаты были очищены сразу. даже если и есть дубли, вы считаете что ихнее отсутствие быстрее справится с таким объёмом ?

Comment: `-i` -- это эквивалент `sed -e '...' < in > out && mv -f out in`. Хотя, надо запускать `strace sed -i ...` и смотреть, что и в какой последовательности вызывается. В разных ОС появляются интересные под час системные вызовы, да и сами файловые системы не стоят на месте.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Нашёл! http://k001.livejournal.com/433451.html Там в комментариях есть ответ на 1й вопрос. Недавно как раз пользовался этой фичей (команда `crc32` не умеет по-другому.