# Из одного файла-списка, удалить слова, находящиеся в другом файле, который используется как шаблон для удаления

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Есть файл1.txt, который содержит слово1, слово2, слово3 и т.д, список длиный, по одному слову на строку. Есть файл2.txt, в нём тоже есть слова(1,2,3 и т.д.) с такой же огранизацией списка. Из файл1.txt нужно удалить слова, находящиеся в файл2.txt, т.е. последний используется как шаблон.
Нашёл похожий вопрос [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626500/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0)
но после выполнения получаю сообщение sed: can't read слово1: No such file or directory. Я не понял, что значит 's,^,/^,;s,$,:/d,', вариант /искомая строка/d более понятен, но не понятно как искомая строка станет шаблоном.

Comment: Если по одному слову в строке, то не знаю, зачем там двоеточие в "программе" внутреннего sed-а. Кстати, он преобразует список слов в список запросов sed-а (можете выполнить `cat <(sed 's,^,/^,;s,$,/d,' f2)` и посмотреть его.  Так что, пробуйте  `sed -i -f <(sed 's,^,/^,;s,$,/d,' f2) f1` (`f2` файл с набором слов, которые надо удалить из `f1`) / По поводу *`"No such file or directory"`* -- это вы что-то не так перетащили (скобочки, кавычки. знак $ и т.п.)

Comment: `'s,^,/^,;s,$,:/d,'` -- это 2 запроса sed-а для редактирования каждой строки (символы `,` это просто разделители (обычно мы пишем `/`, но тут этот символ занят(!)). Первый запрос -- заменить (это символ s) начало строки на `/^`, второй -- заменить конец на `:/d` (про `:` я написал, что это лишнее, а `d` это команда удаления). Т.е. формируется запрос типа `/^word1/d` -- удалить "word1" с начала строки. (Надеюсь, понятно объяснил)

Answer (score 1):

```
cat > ./complete.txt <<EOF
word0
word1
word2
word3
word4
word5
EOF

cat > ./patterns.txt <<EOF
word1
word3
EOF

# 1 вариант

awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' ./patterns.txt ./complete.txt 

# 2 вариант

grep -vf ./patterns.txt < ./complete.txt
```

Comment: `grep -vf ...` хороший способ, но я бы преобразовал паттерны к виду `^word$` (`^` сопостовляется c началом, а `$`  с концом строки, такой образец нужен, чтобы слова вида `123word456` ошибочно не отбрасывались)

Comment: `grep` умеет работать со всеми видами регулярных выражений: PCRE, POSIX, BRE, ERE.
Параметр `-f` говорит, что список паттернов будет в файле. Входящие данные можно направить в стандартный ввод или перечислить файлы последними параметрами.